# WIFI chat with out using server side

Tags: android, wifi

Is it possible to make chat  application over WIFI between two (or more) Android devices with assume that no server-side will be available

If yes, please can you give me sample code

Comment: Is there an access-point involved (note that this is something different than a server!), or will they establish an ad-hoc network? Will they be connected to the same AP? It *might* be possible, in certain cases - but you need to be *much* more specific. Also, what have you tried so far? What worked? What didn't?

Comment: @Piskvor, Yes there is an access-point involved

Comment: Will they be connected to the *same* AP? It might be possible, in certain cases - but you need to be much more specific. Also, what have you tried so far? What worked? What didn't?